# Angular 2 accessing form elements in template

Tags: angular

I have a form that looks as following:

```html
 <form (submit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">E-Mail</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" ngModel required email #email="ngModel">
          {{f.controls.email.valid}}
          <span *ngIf="f.controls.email.valid">Field must be a valid e-mail!</span>
        </div>
```

The value false is correctly rendered inside the {{}}, but I get a console error saying that within ngIf it can't resolve property valid of undefined. I need to use the placeholder `#email="ngModel"` inside my input element and then reference email.valid...

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the very first time when your component is rendered, your form controls won't be created when the bindings are checked.

This means you are probably checking the a property of undefined. It shows correctly in in the interpolation because interpolations finds that the value has been changed inside it and renders the new value.

Modify the binding using the safe navigation operator.

```
f?.controls?.email?.valid
```

Comment: Thanks that works! Which option do you think is better?

Comment: @MrD I didn't follow, which option?

Comment: Between using a local reference (Eg: #email) or the f?.controls?... approach

Comment: @MrD You meant using `intepolation` in `*ngIf`? I would personally not prefer Intepolation for bindings. I beleive Interpolation is meant more for display.

Comment: @MrD oh, that is completely your choice. You can use any and I don't have very specific reasons to justify one over other

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use

```
f.controls.email?.valid
```

instead of f.controls.email?.valid

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing the template-driven approach to the reactive forms.

This is template-driven:

```
#f="ngForm"
```

This is reactive:

```
"f.controls..."
```

From the official docs:

> #name="ngModel" exports NgModel into a local variable called name. NgModel mirrors many of the properties of its underlying FormControl
>   instance, so you can use this in the template to check for control
>   states such as valid and dirty. For a full list of control properties,
>   see the AbstractControl API reference.

https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#template-driven-validation

So, change this:

```
f.controls.email.valid
```

to this:

```
email.valid
```

as you don't need to go through the forms controls to access a FormControl in the template-driven approach.

Hope it helps.